# How to export all routes in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an NodeJS Express app that is getting really big in just one file (app.js).

I want to export all my routes into a single, external file, say `./lib/routes.js`. How to do that?

How to export the following bit of code and require it correctly in main `app.js`?

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    res.render('logout', {
        username: req.session.username
    });
});

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    res.render('dashboard', {
        username: req.session.username
    });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', {
        badLogin: false,
        loginError: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
// logout.js
module.exports = function(req, res){
  res.render('logout', {
    username: req.session.username
  });
});

// dashboard.js
module.exports = function(req, res){
  res.render('dashboard', {
    username: req.session.username
  });
});

// login.js
module.exports = function(req, res){
  res.render('login', {
    badLogin: false,
    loginError: false
  });
});

// app.js
app.get('/logout', require('logout'));
app.get('/dashboard', require('dashboard'));
app.get('/login', require('login'));
```

Also, you could imagine easily using http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/fs.html#fs.readdir to loop through a *routes* directory and load these up programmatically.

You could even do something along the lines of...

```
module.exports.handler[] = {
    method : 'get',
    route  : '/login',
    action : res.render('login', {
       badLogin: false,
       loginError: false
    });
}
```

Though I think I'd spend a little time thinking about how to simplify that.

Answer (score 22):

What I do is group my routes by controller.  For each group of related routes (users, shopping cart, whatever), I make a controller file that lives in `app/controllers/foo.js` where `foo` is the controller name.  In my main javascript server file (where all your code currently lives), I `require` each controller by name and then call its `setup` function, passing in my express `app` object, and allow the controller to add whatever routes it needs.

```
['api', 'authorization', 'users', 'tests'].map(function(controllerName) {
    var controller = require('./controllers/' + controllerName);
    controller.setup(app);
 });
```

Inside each controller, I do something like:

```
exports.setup = function(app) {
    app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
        res.render('dashboard', {
            username: req.session.username
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there an easy solution for passing variables between two modules?

Comment: oooh, I like how clean that becomes with the passed in strings as an argument, I hadn't considered that one before ... you could, of course, parse the directory where all controllers live using a fs object and get them all there really quickly as well, yeah?

Comment: Yup you could also just load them all in the directory.  In my case I need to make sure they are loaded in the correct order so I specify it explicitly, but if all your controllers are independent then you could just list the directory and load them all.

Comment: Just starting with Node, and came across this answer. Really like this approach, move the route declaration out of app.js and into "controllers" where they belong. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

using glob you can export all routes on directory for example '/routes':

> npm i --save glob

```
    // *** /routes/index.js file ***

    const express = require('express')
    const Router = express.Router
    const router = Router()
    const glob = require('glob')


    /**
     * options ignore files inside routes folder
     */
    const options = {
        ignore: [`${__dirname}/_helpers.js`, `${__dirname}/index.js`]
    }

    /**
     * read all files on current directory and export routes as lowercase of the filename
     * example 'routes/Products.js' route will be access by '/products'
     */
    const routes = 
        glob.sync(__dirname + '/*.js', options)
            .map(filename => {
                const arr = filename.split('/')
                let name = arr.pop();
                name = name.replace('.js', '')
                return {
                    path: `/${name.toLowerCase()}`,
                    router: require(`${filename.replace('.js', '')}`)
                }
            })
            .filter(obj => Object.getPrototypeOf(obj.router) == Router)
            .forEach(obj => router.use(obj.path, obj.router))


    module.exports = router;
```

then

> on app.js

```
// app.js file

const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')


const app = express()

app.use('/api', routes)
```